# Passportjs: Local strategy is never called and automatically redirects to failureRedirect

Tags: node.js, authentication, express, passport.js

Given the following form:

```
<form action="/login" method="post">
      <div>
        <label>Username:</label>
        <input type="text" name="username" />
        <br/>
      </div>
      <div>
        <label>Password:</label>
        <input type="password" name="password" />
      </div>
      <div>
        <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
      </div>
</form>
```

And express route:

```
app.post('/login', passport.authenticate('local', {
    successRedirect: '/app', 
    failureRedirect: '/login', 
    failureFlash: false 
}));
```

And local strategy definition:

```
passport.use(new LocalStrategy(function(username, password, done) {
    console.log('FTW!');
}));
```

Why is it that I never see 'FTW!' in console? It always automatically redirects me to the failureRedirect no matter what. I can't figure out for the life of me how to debug this?

Answer (score 0):

I had forgot to include the express body parser:

```
app.use( express.bodyParser());
```

Comment: I was just about to mention that you should check your app middleware :). Next time, you can rely on this form of the invocation: `passport.authenticate("local", function(error, user, info) {...}` to be able to pause and debug the issue at hand.